Pycharm, python, selenium practice with scrapping issues
Im new to coding. What does this mean, and how do I fix it? This is the error Im getting:
At line:1 char:1
+ from selenium import webdriver
+ ~~~~
The 'from' keyword is not supported in this version of the language.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ReservedKeywordNotAllowed

I did this part correctly with no issues: "pip install selenium webdriver-manager"
But when I move to the next step, "from selenium import webdriver", I get the error above.
Apologies if this is a dumb question. I appreciate your help and patience! :)
Im following the, "How To Scrape Reddit in Python Guide".

You're entering Python code into your PowerShell command line instead of into the Python interpreter.

Your question title mentions Pycharm. Are you not running your code from there?

Issue: Writing Python Code Directly in PowerShell Without Opening Python Shell First
Description:
I've noticed that you are attempting to write Python code directly in PowerShell without opening the Python shell first. This can lead to confusion and errors, as PowerShell isn't designed to execute Python code directly in its shell.
Solution:
Instead of attempting to write Python code directly within the PowerShell environment, you can open the Python interpreter separately. Here's how to do it:

Open PowerShell as usual.
Type python (or python3 on Linux/Unix systems) and press Enter.
This command opens the Python interpreter, displaying the Python version information and a >>> prompt, indicating that you're now in the Python shell.
You can now write your Python code directly within this environment. For example:

deepesh@devdas:~$ python3
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("Hello world")
Hello world
>>> 



After writing your code, press Enter to execute it. You'll see the output immediately.
To exit the Python shell and return to PowerShell, type exit() and press Enter.

Recommendation:
Instead of writing Python code directly in PowerShell, it's best practice to write your Python code in a separate file with a .py extension. You can then run this Python script by invoking the Python interpreter from within PowerShell. Here's how you can do it:

Open your preferred text editor (e.g., Notepad, Visual Studio Code).
Write your Python code in a new file, and save it with a .py extension (e.g., script.py).
Open PowerShell.
Navigate to the directory where your Python script is saved, using the cd command.
Once in the correct directory, run the Python script by typing python script.py and pressing Enter.

This approach separates your Python code from PowerShell commands, ensuring clarity and proper execution. If you encounter any issues or have further questions, feel free to ask!
